# How to dynamically create fields in form based on user input from selectfield?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

How to generate form fields based on user input on select fields?

```py
class PracticeForm(FlaskForm):
    number_of_fields = SelectField(u'How many input fields?', choices=[(2, '2'), (3, '3'), (4, '4'), (5, '5'), (6, '6')])

    '''
    dynamically create input fields based on user input of "number_of_fields" here

    fields = number_of_fields (ranging from 2-6) **** StringFields with same attributes
    '''

    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

In my routes.py, I would like to save the fields to a list:

```py
@app.route("/practice", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def practice():

    practiceform = PracticeForm()
    user_list = practiceform.fields.data
    if practiceform.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('success_page', list=user_list))
```

How should I format my form and how would I format my html page in jinja2, so that it shows the SelectField and the number of input string fields based on number in the SelectField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you'll need to do this by leaning on jQuery/javascript-- but here's the rough example to get you going:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import FieldList, StringField, SelectField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'TEST'


class PracticeForm(FlaskForm):
    min_choices, max_choices = 2, 6
    choices = [(x, str(x)) for x in range(min_choices, max_choices)]
    number_of_fields = SelectField(u'How many input fields?', choices=choices, coerce=int)
    data_field = FieldList(StringField('Data'), min_entries=min_choices, max_entries=max_choices)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def example():
    form = PracticeForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form.data_field.data)
        print(form.number_of_fields.data)
    else:
        print(form.errors)

    return render_template('example.html', form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The magic is the `FieldList`-- now the validator will accept multiple entries for that `StringField` (between min and max) and it'll validate just fine.

Your trick is now to read the value of the SelectField using jQuery-- two will be displayed by default (since it's the min) so just have a look at the code for that, you'll just want to watch to see if the `SelectField` value changes, and do something..

For example-- if SelectField changed to 3-- you'd need to insert:

```
<li>
    <label for="data_field-2">Data</label>
    <input id="data_field-2" name="data_field-2" type="text" value="">
</li>
```

Here's a really rough pass at the jQuery required that just wipes the `<ul>` and rebuilds it based on the number of fields chosen.

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.number_of_fields }}
    {{ form.data_field }}

    <input type="submit"/>

</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function range(start, end) {
        return Array(end - start).fill().map((_, idx) => start + idx)
    }

    $('#number_of_fields').on('change', function() {
        $('#data_field').empty();
        range(0, (this.value * 1)).forEach(function(element) {
            const reference = element;
            $('#data_field').append(
              '<li>' +
                '<label for="data_field-'+ reference + '">Data</label> ' +
                '<input id="data_field-'+reference+'" name="data_field-'+reference+'" type="text" value="">' +
                '</li>'
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is a great start to what I needed! Thanks!